# Racket, get a value from a list using an index

Tags: racket

I want to get a element from a list giving an index. But the index will by get trough another function:

```
    #lang racket

(define (list-index e lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        0
        (if (equal? (car lst) (car e))
            1
            (+ 1 (list-index e (cdr lst))))))


(list-ref '(aa bb cc dd ee ff) (list-index e lst))
```

Example:
If I execute: (list-index '(c) '(a b c d)) this returns "3" and now I want to use that number to get "cc" in the second funtion with the list '(aa bb cc dd ee ff).

The issues are:

- The (list-index e lst) is giving an error in the second function.
- I dont know how to combine both funtions.

Comment: The error is because you don't pass the same value. What is the global `e`? Is probably not the same as your quoted list..

Answer (score 0):

First, note that [`list-ref`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list-ref#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29) considers first element at position 0, so

```
(list-ref '(aa bb cc dd ee ff) 3)
```

would output `'dd`, not *cc*.

Second, `(list-index e lst)` is producing an error because both *e* and *lst* are undefined/unbound variables within the expression. To apply the procedure (or any function in general), you have to pass it actual values, or identifiers bound to values within scope. For example, the following would work and output `'dd`:

```
> (list-ref '(aa bb cc dd ee ff) (list-index '(c) '(a b c d)))
'dd
```

To output *cc*, you can do

```
(list-ref '(aa bb cc dd ee ff) (sub1 (list-index '(c) '(a b c d))))
'cc
```

or you can modify `list-index` itself to output 0-indexed positions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It has been very useful for me

Comment: You're welcome, and if you need help with variable scopes, perhaps [this](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/11b-how-functions-work/) or [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scope_(computer_science)) will be helpful.